# Choosing Iterator when using TAB Reader in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, mapinfo, iterator, tab

I have added the TAB Reader 5.2 tool to a model; [TAB Reader (from DataEast)](http://www.dataeast.com/en/tabreader.asp) can convert multiple MapInfo tab files to ArcGIS format. However, I would like to iterate through many folders, each of which has tab files.

**Is there a proper iterator type to use for this?** I have tried using "feature Classes" and "Files" but am subsequently unable to link them up to the TAB Reader tool.

I'm on ArcGIS for Desktop - Advanced v10.3.1

[image]

Comment: Can you please include a snapshot of the dialog/window of this tool? Also what happens once you right click on the tool and go to Make Variable>From Parameter option?

Comment: Try iterating tables.  You could also add a python script to capture all the file paths in a list using the os module.